# how can i set prefix path for thymeleaf in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

How can I set the prefix path(set the new directory) to render the HTML page?

I have a spring boot application. I am using version 2.1.7.

- I am set a new path for view page.

Comment: Add the following line in Application.properties

"spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/views/ "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following line in Application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/views/    #this is the main
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: I had to use `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/`

Answer (score 3):

You can use basic setup or by overriding a property in application.properties to give your own customise page.

A prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/config/templates/
```